# interrupt behaviour on 6502

Tags: emulation, interrupt, 6502

A quick and stupid question about 6502. For example, the instruction NOP takes 2 cycles. If an interrupt occurs on 6502, can it occur in between the 2 cycles of the NOP?

So, is this a possible scenario:

```
NOP cycle 1
[ INTERRUPT ]
NOP cycle 2
```

Of course this question extends for other instructions. Will interrupt "wait" for the whole instruction to finish or can it disrupt the instruction itself?

Comment: The current instruction finishes first: _"When a peripheral device needs service and pulls the interrupt request (IRQ) line low, **the currently executing machine-language instruction is allowed to finish**, and the 7-clock interrupt sequence is started.  This sequence is like the execution of an instruction that was not written into the program, but implicitly inserted by the fact that the IRQ line was pulled down to a logic-low level. "_ ([source](http://wilsonminesco.com/6502interrupts/))

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted to know!

Comment: Something to know is that the interrupt is only checked on the penultimate cycle of the instruction. If it happens after this point then the processor waits until after the next instruction to service the interrupt.

Answer (score 3):

Rounding up the comments as a Community Wiki:

The current instruction [finishes first](http://wilsonminesco.com/6502interrupts/): "When a peripheral device needs service and pulls the interrupt request (IRQ) line low, the currently executing machine-language instruction is allowed to finish, and the 7-clock interrupt sequence is started. This sequence is like the execution of an instruction that was not written into the program, but implicitly inserted by the fact that the IRQ line was pulled down to a logic-low level."

Interrupt status is checked only on the penultimate cycle of an instruction; therefore if an interrupt request is ongoing but the interrupt disable flag is set before the sequence:

```
CLI
SEI
```

Then the following will occur:

- one cycle before the end of CLI, the interrupt disable flag is still set so nothing happens after CLI;
- one cycle before the end of SEI, the interrupt disable flag is now disabled so an interrupt is scheduled;
- the SEI sets the interrupt disable flag; and
- the interrupt request is then honoured, resulting in a `P` on the stack with the interrupt disable flag set.

Comment: SEI is the typical mnemonic used to SEt Interrupt disable